# Strategies to prove that a polynomial always has a root in an interval

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

We have $f(x) = 1-x-x^a+x^{b}$, valid only for $|x| < 1$, integers $a, b$ such that $1 < a < b$, and $b-a \geq 2$

What approaches would one take to prove that this polynomial always has a root in $(0,1)$, for any integers $a, b$ constrained as above. I'm looking for the simplest possible procedures that would prove the existence of a root in that interval, not necessarily ones that produce said root.

Comment: If you plot a few of them then a good strategy may present itself.

Comment: This is how (I think) I know the answer, but cannot yet prove it. What kinds of strategies do you have in mind?

Comment: One obvious strategy is to prove that it is negative somewhere and postive somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions on $a,b$ imply that $b=a+n$ for some integer $n≥2$.  We write:

$$f(x)=1-x-x^a+x^{a+n}=(1-x)+x^a(x^n-1)$$ $$\implies f(x)=(1-x)(1-x^a(x^{n-1}+\cdots +1))$$

Letting $$g(x)=1-x^a(x^{n-1}+\cdots +1)$$
your goal is to show that $g(x)$ has a root in the desired open interval.

But $g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=1-n$.

Noting that $n≥2$, we are done.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say a few words about what is involved in the steps indicated with $= ... =$? Everything else is crystal clear.

Comment: Oh, there are no omitted steps.  The thing just wouldn't fit on one line.  All I do is invoke the usual factoring, $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\cdots +1)$.  I'll edit to clarify that nothing significant was left off.

Comment: What about $f(x)$ being only valid for $|x| < 1$? (You write $g(1) = ...)$

Comment: I don't understand. These functions are all defined and continuous at $1$, clearly.  if you prefer, you could write $\lim_{x\to 1^-}g(x)$ instead of $g(1)$ (though of course they are equal).

Comment: Well I'm considering, for example, when $f(x)$ is the denominator of a rational function. I'm wondering how your approach works in such a case.

Comment: Still not following.  My approach depended crucially on the form of the functions.  If you had radically different functions, the argument would be different. But, anyway, just use the limit.  Since $\lim_{x\to 1^-}g(x)<0$ it must be the case that $g(1-\epsilon)<0$ for small positive $\epsilon$.  That's enough.